# Not working deletion from the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tell me, what could be the problem? I do everything as it should be, but constantly displays 'Error'.
Controller:

```
<?php
  class Boss extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() 
  {
      parent:: __construct();

      $this->load->model('boss_model');
      $this->load->model('news_model');
      $this->load->model('reviews_model');
  }

  public function index()
  {
      if($this->userlib->logged_in_boss() == FALSE)
          show_404();



      $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
      $data['reviews'] = $this->reviews_model->get_reviews();

      $this->load->view('boss/main.php', $data);
}

public function review_del($id)
{
      $delete = $this->reviews_model->del_review($id);

      if($delete)
      {
          echo "Success";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Error";
      }
  }
}
```

reviews_model:

```
<?php
class Reviews_model extends CI_Model {

public function del_review($id = null)
{
    $this->db->delete('reviews', array('id' => $id));
}
}
```

P.S. - table 'reviews' is not empty, 'database' including in autoload.php

Comment: And where is $id defined?

Comment: I write example.com/boss/review_del/1 and displays false :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del_review` doesn't return a value, so `$delete` never gets a proper result value, and always evaluates to false. So the delete itself `might` have succeeded already, but you'll never know. ;)

Easiest: Change like this:

```
public function del_review($id = null)
{
    return $this->db->delete('reviews', array('id' => $id));
}
```

I think this should return whether the delete statement itself was successful. That doesn't tell you whether an actual row was deleted. Maybe it was deleted before by somebody else. If you want to check for that, you can use this:

```
public function del_review($id = null)
{
    $this->db->delete('reviews', array('id' => $id));
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

This executes the delete statement, and afterwards checks if an actual row was deleted. So you get the error also when you try to delete a record that isn't there.